# Can I leave Italy for another Schengen country before getting my permesso di soggiorno?

Tags: schengen, italy

I will be studying in Italy for one year, and I already have my student visa.
I arrive in September and I want to visit the Oktoberfest in Munich, Germany (just for one weekend) the same week that I arrive to Italy.

I know I have to get my codice fiscale and permesso di soggiorno in the first 8 working days after my arrival, and I'm wondering if I can leave and re-enter Italy before getting those papers, or if they are absolutely necessary for re-entering Italy.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: What does it matter his nationality? He has a valid Schengen visa for Italy; and there are no border controls between Italy and Germany.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid 1. There is no border between Germany and Italy. 2. There were border controls between Italy and Austria last winter. 3. There are different types of Schengen Visas. Type D (that's the visa that foreign students normally get in their homeland) usually does not allow visiting other countries. That is why OP has to get permesso di sogiorno (this will be Type C) in Italy. And the airport officer will probably want to see the OP's visa.

Comment: @Alex.S: A type D visa does allow visiting other Schengen countries, exactly the same as a residence permit does. "Type C" are short-stay visas and have nothing to do with residence permits.

Comment: The only difference I know of between D and C is the duration of stay; C is a short stay visa; all other benefits are the same; and other restrictions are the same as well (if you visit another country other than the one issuing the D visa, you have to abide by the 90/180 rule). I don't know why you are mentioning Austria, the OP is talking about Germany and Italy.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, my fault. I wrongly understood expression "national visa" in description of type D. I mentioned Austria, because the OP would cross the German-Austrian border going by land.

Answer (score 4):

If the student visa you already have is a uniform type D visa, then it allows you to make short visits to the other Schengen states.

I don't know whether leaving Italy is going to jeopardize any local Italian bureaucratic procedure that you've already started at that point, though. (And [Expats](//expatriates.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask that, anyway). I'd guess *probably not* -- the Italian authorities have little reason to even know that you go on a weekend trip to Germany.

But to play it safe, if you have 8 *working* days from your first arrival to file a local application, a possible strategy might be to file only after you get back from Munich.